# Getting column values from a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, .net-datatable

Is there a way I can make the code compact and with fewer `if`s?

```
theData = GetData();
if (theData.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    MyModel = new CustomModel();
    dataSetRow = theData.Rows[0];
    if (theData.Columns.Contains("Column1"))
    {
        if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column1"], DBNull.Value)))
        {
            MyModel.Column1 = Convert.ToString(dataSetRow["Column1"]);
        }
    }
    if (theData.Columns.Contains("Column2"))
    {
        if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column2"], DBNull.Value)))
        {
            MyModel.Column2 = Convert.ToString(dataSetRow["Column2"]);
        }
    }
    if (theData.Columns.Contains("Column3"))
    {
        if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column3"], DBNull.Value)))
        {
            MyModel.Column3 = Convert.ToString(dataSetRow["Column3"]);
        }
    }
    if (theData.Columns.Contains("Column4"))
    {
        if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column4"], DBNull.Value)))
        {
            MyModel.Column4 = Convert.ToString(dataSetRow["Column4"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see 4 very similar blocks. Reduce them to one by using a loop over the constants "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"

Comment: Is this real code ?

Comment: @MrSmith42 `MyModel.Column3` would not be replacable by `MyModel["Column3"]` or something similar as it is a property of a class.

Comment: @Abbas You are right but you can still use a loop and use the loop index to select 'MyModel.Column1' to 'MyModel.Column4' which you stored in an array.

Comment: How are you going to select the property with an indexer without using reflection?

Comment: If I am correct in assuming that dataSetRow is a `DataRow` object: you should probably use [`DataRow.IsNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataRow.IsNull(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `object.ReferenceEquals` with `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: @DanLyons - He's only checking if a specific cell is null not the whole row.

Comment: @tinstaafl `IsNull` does check a cell - it takes in an int/string to identify the column within that row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Useful property names:**

I find using names as `theData` bad practice. It doesn't give *any* info on the instance. Give it a useful name you, and others, easily understand.

**Casing of property names:**

Don't use **P**ascal**C**ase for local fields, use **c**amel**C**ase instead. Your `MyModel` will become `myModel`. You had already done this correctly for `dataSetRow`.

**Redundant parentheses:**

Following:

```
if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column1"], DBNull.Value)))
```

can be replaced by:

```
if (!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column1"], DBNull.Value))
```

There's no need to encapsulate the whole expression again in parantheses.

**Simplifying the code:**

Finally, the important part! :) There's only one way I can think of to achieve this: **reflection**. I created following extension method to get the `PropertyInfo` of your instance (note that it doesn't have to be placed in an extension method, I only think it looks cleaner and is good for reusability elsewhere if needed):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(this T obj, string propertyName) where T : class
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

The above allows you to do following (get a property by it's name-value):

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var user = new User { ID = 1, Name = "Simsons" };
var nameProp = user.GetProperty("Name");
```

And now you can get and/or set the value of that property using the [**GetValue()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) or [**SetValue()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) methods:

```
nameProp.SetValue(user, "Abbas", null);
```

With this in mind, add following changes to your code:

- place all your column names in an array over which you will loop
- simplify your code using the reflection part

Here's your code with the above applied:

```
theData = GetData();

if (theData.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    myModel = new CustomModel();
    dataSetRow = theData.Rows[0];
    var columnNames = new [] { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4" };

    foreach(var columName in columnNames)
    {
        if(theData.Columns.Contains(columName))
        {
            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow[columName], DBNull.Value))
            {
                var columnProperty = myModel.GetProperty(columName);
                columnProperty.SetValue(myModel, Convert.ToString(dataSetRow[columnName], null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

As *RobH* stated in the comments, you can use LinQ to avoid nested if statements. Here's how your code would look like:

```
var columnNames = new [] { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4" };

foreach(var existingColumn in columnNames.Where(x => theData.Columns.Contains(x)))
{
    if (!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow[existingColumn], DBNull.Value))
    {
        var columnProperty = myModel.GetProperty(existingColumn);
        columnProperty.SetValue(myModel, Convert.ToString(dataSetRow[existingColumn], null);
    }
}
```

You can even take it a final step further to avoid *any* if statement:

```
var validColumns = columnNames.Where(x => theData.Columns.Contains(x) &&
                                          !object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow[x], DBNull.Value)))

foreach(var column in validColumns)
{
    var columnProperty = myModel.GetProperty(existingColumn);
    columnProperty.SetValue(myModel, Convert.ToString(dataSetRow[existingColumn], null);
}
```

Comment: +1. You could convert most of that foreach to LINQ though, might look a bit nicer than the nested ifs.

Comment: @RobH Thanks for the tip, updated my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you can refactor your model class so that the column names and values are in a dictionary instead of separate properties everything an be simplified to one LINQ statement:

```
class CustomModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> ColumnValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Column1", "" },
            { "Column2", "" },
            { "Column3", "" },
            { "Column4", "" }
        };
}

var dataSetRow = theData.Rows[0];
CustomModel MyModel = new CustomModel();
MyModel.ColumnValues = (from DataColumn c in theData.Columns
                    where MyModel.ColumnValues.ContainsKey(c.ColumnName) && dataSetRow[c] != DBNull.Value
                    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(c.ColumnName, dataSetRow[c].ToString())).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```